# Matplotlib Event Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors

I'm looking to create this kind of plot in python.

Description:

x-axis is time interval. ( resampled on 10 mins interval)

y-axis is alarm type.

values: those values talk about how many times a alarm rang in 10 mins interval. higher the value, darker the color.

## Expected Output

[image]

## Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Date Timestamp': [pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:10:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:20:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:30:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31 17:40:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31 20:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31 21:00:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31 21:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-31 22:40:00')],
      'PDAH-3190': [12, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'LAL-3801B': [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0],
      'FALL-3452A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'FAL-3452A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
      'AAHH-3032': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'LAL-3507': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      'LAL-3385': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'AAH-3042': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'LAL-3801C': [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
      'TAL-3730A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d1)

       Date Timestamp  PDAH-3190  LAL-3801B  FALL-3452A  FAL-3452A  AAHH-3032  LAL-3507  LAL-3385  AAH-3042  LAL-3801C  TAL-3730A
0 2019-12-01 00:00:00         12          0           0          0          1         0         0         0          0          0
1 2019-12-01 00:10:00          0          0           0          0          1         0         0         0          0          0
2 2019-12-01 00:20:00          0          0           0          0          2         0         0         0          2          0
3 2019-12-01 00:30:00          0          6           0          0          1         0         0         0          0          0
4 2019-12-01 01:00:00          3          0           7          0          1         0         0         0          0          7
5 2019-12-31 17:40:00          0          0           0          0          0         1         0         0          0          0
6 2019-12-31 20:00:00          0          0           0          0          0         1         0         0          3          0
7 2019-12-31 21:00:00          0          9           0          0          0         1         0         0          0          0
8 2019-12-31 21:30:00          0          0           0          0          0         1         0         0          0          0
9 2019-12-31 22:40:00          0          0           0          4          0         1         0         0          0          9
```

## What I have tried

```
x_ticks=np.array(data['Date Timestamp'])
x_ticks_1=pd.date_range(start=x_ticks.min(), end=x_ticks.max())
data=data.drop(['Date Timestamp'],axis=1)
positions = (data.apply(lambda x: data.index[x > 0] ))

colorsCodes = ['C{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_1,rotation = 45)
plt.eventplot(positions,color=colorsCodes,linelengths =0.8)
plt.yticks(range(positions.index.size), positions.index)
ax.set_facecolor("white")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

## Output:

[image]

## Issue

The color coding should be based on the actual value. in my chart/code, it is based on whether some value exists for a particular time period or not.

## Update

I tried couple of more things but still not able to create what I exactly need.

```
test=data[['PDAH-3190']]
test.reset_index(inplace=True)

test=test[test['PDAH-3190']!=0]
test['PDAH-3190'] =test['PDAH-3190']/255

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
ax.set_facecolor("white")
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_1,rotation = 45)
ax.set_yticklabels('')
ax.set(xlabel="TimeStamp",ylabel='PDAH-3190')
# iterate through each group and plot
for i, (label, data1) in enumerate(test.groupby('PDAH-3190')):
    ax.eventplot('Date Timestamp', colors='C{}'.format(i), data=data1, label=label,linelengths=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [Vertical "broken" bar plot with arrays as bar heights and color coding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63859980/7758804)

Comment: It might simpler to use a heatmap: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMDdj.png)

Comment: Which option did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TrentonMcKinney for providing the solution. Adding the answer here.

## Solution

```
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel")
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(32,20))
sns_plot=sns.heatmap(data[200:300],ax=ax,mask=(data[200:300]==0),cmap='YlGnBu',linewidth=1)
```

Original data was too big so just using 100 rows randomly.

Output:

[image]